# Populating variable values in dropdown / radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I populate a dropdown / radio button from a model with a variable values from the model, e.g.:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I have the value of the car in the model, and `${modelObject.selectedcar}`
prints the variable's value on UI... but how do I initially select it in the dropdown / radio button on page load?

I have tried using a script, but it seems the script doesn't get values from the model, and I don't know how to do it without a script since the value of the selected car is variable.

Comment: You want to populate as an option or want to select that option in the selectedCar?

Comment: i have tried using script  .. java script on pageload ... but javascript .. but it seems jvascript doesnt entertain values from model

Comment: On page load:
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cars").value = “${modelAttribute.selectedCar}”;
}

Comment: @PankajShukla. i want to select that option

Comment: Please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a6x6bq2v/ .I guess what you are looking for

Comment: @Shiladitya

you are hard coding the car value .. the car value is variable.
var selectedCar = {
 test: "saab"
};


$('#cars').val(selectedCar.test);
here  test should be assigned the value from model .. something like modelAttribute.selectedcar

Comment: thnaks all .. got the solution. ..we have to use something called modelmap ... it wiil directly map your attribute with getterData .. I am using Spring 
ModelMap m;
m.addAttribute("cars",modelObject.getSelectedCar());

in JSP script:

function myFunction(){
var x="${cars}";
    document.getElementById("cars").value=x;

}